# Cart throb: One product simply order one product with multiple colors in numerous quantities

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, shopping-cart

Cart throb: 
I want to have the ability in CT to have a single product and say order 10 black, 20 green adn 5 yellow all with a single add to cart click

RIght now I have to add each color individually.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the multi_add_to_cart_form. Assuming that the price modifier for your colors is called "product_color" your form would look something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
    {exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form return="TEMPLATE_GROUP/TEMPLATE"}     
           Product name: {title} Price: {product_price}<br />
           {product_color}
               {option_name}: <input type="text" name="quantity[{count}]" value="0" /><br />
               <input type="hidden" name="entry_id[{count}]" value="{entry_id}" />
               <input type="hidden" name="item_options[{count}][product_color]" value="{option_value}" />
           {/product_color}
           <p><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"></p>
    {/exp:cartthrob:multi_add_to_cart_form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

That will give you a form with your color options printed out with corresponding quantity fields.